# "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" in viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, swift, fatal-error

Here is my code:

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    if let vid = self.selectedVideo {

        self.titleLabel.text = vid.videoTitle
        self.descriptionLabel.text = vid.videoDescription

        let width = self.view.frame.size.width
        let height = width/320 * 180

        let videoEmbedString = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">body {background-color: transparent;color: white;}</style></head><body style=\"margin:0\"><iframe frameBorder=\"0\" height=\"" + String(height) + "\" width=\"" + String(width) + "\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + vid.videoId + "?showinfo=0&modestbranding=1&frameborder=0&rel=0\"></iframe></body></html>"

        self.webView.loadHTMLString(videoEmbedString, baseURL: nil)
    }
}
```

I have problems on the last line:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   (lldb)

Comment: What is self.webView? Its IBOutlet object?

Comment: @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

Comment: Are you using an implicitly unwrapped `Optional` in your code? It would look like `Type!`  - if so then the `Optional` is not getting set before it's being used.

Comment: @AydosKurmashev, Please check wether you have done proper binding of webView object in storyboard.

Comment: @NileshPatel Binding?

Comment: @KennethBruno Yeah binding it.. Typos..

Comment: @NileshPatel I figured! They do creep into the worst places.

Comment: don't forget to call super.viewDidAppear. it's not the reason for the crash in the topic, but it may cause issues in future...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Confirm that the outlet is hooked up correctly by examining the left margin and making sure you have a solid dot next to each `@IBOutlet`. For example, below, since there is an empty dot next to the `webView` declaration, I know I didn't hook up the outlet correctly, and therefore it will be `nil` resulting in an error like yours:

[image]

Whenever you get this error, "unexpectedly found nil", identify which variable was `nil` and then diagnose why it might be so.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that webView is probably declared as a (weak) implicitly unwrapped optional type and that is causing the error message to appear when you are trying to use it. Wrap your code with a guard and make sure you have connected your webview correctly in IB.